# Let $X$ be the value of the first die and $Y$ the sum of the two dice. Find $E(X / Y)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, martingales

Consider an experiment of rolling two dice. Let $X$ be the value of the first die and $Y$ the sum of the two dice. Find $E(X / Y)$, ie, obtain the value of $E(x/y) (y)$ for all $y$

Good evening, I could solve the problem. I have no idea how to start. You could give me some tips to solve it, please. Or some bibliographic references with similar exercises?

Comment: $E(X|Y) = \sum_{x} x p(x|y) = \sum_{x} x \frac{p(x,y)}{p(y)}$ ?

Comment: You can try "An Introduction to Mathematical Statistics and Its Applications" by Larsen and Marx

Comment: Think of the fact that you know the sum of the die (Y=y) as reducing your sample space (i.e. the different kind of pairs of die it could be (face of die 1, face of die 2)) then you have that each of these pairs are likely as one another, with this fact you can derive the expectation (conditioned on the fact you know sum of die)

Comment: Do you mean $\mathrm{E}(X/Y)$ or $\mathrm{E}(X\mid Y)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean $\mathrm{E}(X|Y)$, then since the distribution of each die is identical and independent, if we are given that their sum is $y$, the expected value of each die would be the same: $y/2$.

If you did mean $\mathrm{E}(X/Y)$, then in light of the preceding, this would be $\frac12$.

---

**Explicit Calculation of $\boldsymbol{\mathrm{E}(X|Y)}$**

Given that the sum of the dice is $y$, the possibilities for $x$ are from $y-6$ to $6$ with equal probability of each. That is, the probability that the first die is $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ is
$$
\frac1{13-y}[y-6\le x\le6]
$$
where the brackets are [Iverson brackets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).

Thus, the expected value would be
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{x=y-6}^6\frac{x}{13-y}
&=\frac{\frac126(6+1)-\frac12(y-7)(y-6)}{13-y}\\
&=\frac{21-21+\frac{13}2y-\frac12y^2}{13-y}\\[9pt]
&=\frac y2
\end{align}
$$
This nicely agrees with the symmetry argument given above.

Answer (score 2):

We show how to handle the problem for one value of $y$, say $y=9$.

Given that $Y=9$, $X$ takes on values $3$ to $6$ with equal probabilities. Thus $$E(X|Y=9)=\frac{3+4+5+6}{4}.$$

One value of $y$ done, $10$ more to do.

**Remark:** The symmetry argument of robjohn is much better.